# Leaflet MarkerCluster open/spiderfy cluster based on known marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

My scenario is that the user would click on a marker that is part of a cluster and be redirected somewhere else. Then when they come back they need to return the the same bounds on the map where they were before at that marker, but the cluster in which the marker is found is no longer expanded/spiderfy'd, which I need to get done.

At this point I know which marker I'm looking for, but need to expand its cluster. What I've done so far:

Iterate through the markers in the initially populated `L.markerClusterGroup()` object:

```
layers = L.markerClusterGroup();

. . . populate 'layers' ...

$.each(layers, function (idx, layer) {
    if(layer._tooltip._content === 'known marker tooltip') {
        layer.__parent.spiderfy();
    }
});
```

Although the `spiderfy()` function sort of works, it doesn't seem to be intended to be used on its own and breaks the cluster pretty bad.

Alternatively, I've tried calling `fire('clusterclick')` on the above `layer` object, as well as on `layer.__parent`, which I presume would represent the cluster, but can't get anything working.

I would need a solution in which I can properly trigger the `clusterclick` event that would handle everything, as if I had actually clicked the cluster myself.